# How to show a message instead of hiding the webform when user reaches the limit?

Tags: webforms

I have a webform which every user can submit it once. when the user submits the form the webform gets hidden from him next time he visits the site. I want to be able to show a message or something which describes why the visitor can not see the form anymore. How can may I do this?

Comment: Are you using webform as block?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Yes.